# Update one attribute of a Symfony doctrine object when another changes

Tags: symfony1, triggers, doctrine

In a symfony 1.4 project I have Doctrine object `book` that has a number of attributes including `owner` and `owner_updated_at`. I would like to have the field `owner_updated_at` set to the current date and time any time the value of `owner` is changed. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Timestampable](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/pl/behaviors%3acore-behaviors%3atimestampable) behavior, it is its purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In your `schema.yml`:

```
Book:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~ # for time
    Signable: ~ # for owners
```